# Set an interval for every 12 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I need a function to run initially and then to rerun at 12pm and 12am. I'm using VueJS if that has any influence.

```
fetch_datetime()
{
    axios.get('/api/core/datetime').then((response) => {
        this.datetime = response.data;
        this.set_interval();
    });
},

set_interval()
{
    var current_date = new Date();
    var hours = current_date.getHours();
    var minutes = current_date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = current_date.getSeconds();
    if(hours == 12 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0 || hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0)
    {
        this.fetch_datetime();
    } else
    {
        if(hours >= 12)
        {
            setTimeout(this.fetch_datetime, (1000 * (60 - seconds) * (60 - minutes)) + (1000 * 60 * (24 - hours - 1) * 60));
        } else
        {
            setTimeout(this.fetch_datetime, (1000 * (60 - seconds) * (60 - minutes)) + (1000 * 60 * (12 - hours - 1) * 60));
        }
    }
```

However this isn't working as expected and the function runs early and then runs multiple times on the hour.

Comment: Who's going to leave their browser open for 12 hours to run the function again?

Comment: The idea is that if the user accesses the site at 11:50, the function needs to run again at 12:00.

Comment: The better question is: Did Imagine17 really wait 12 hours to see if it does work or not :D

Comment: Its pretty easy to test. And as I said, the function runs early then runs multiple times on the hour.

Comment: I think we are missing something.  What's inside fetch_datetime() ?

Comment: `fetch_datetime()` is mentioned in the code above. It's just calling an api.

Comment: Does it need to be 12am and 12pm exactly? That's just not an intended use-case for javascript at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple function that can do what you want. It should fit your use case (refresh after some minutes) but don't expect it to be very resilient on browser changes.

```js
// Takes an array of hours as number and a function to execute
function executeOnHours(hours, callback) {
  callback(); // First, execute once
  let now = new Date();
  const hoursWithToogle = hours.map(h => {
    return {
      value: h,
      executedToday: now.getHours() === h // Don't run now if already on the given hour
    }
  });
  setInterval(() => {
    now = new Date();
    const triggers = hoursWithToogle.filter(h => {
      if (!h.executedToday && h.value === now.getHours()) {
        return h.executedToday = true;
      } else if (h.value !== now.getHours()) {
        h.executedToday = false; // Clean the boolean on the next hour
      }
    });
    if (triggers.length) callback(); // Trigger the action if some hours match
  }, 30000); // Fix a precision for the check, here 30s
}

executeOnHours([0, 12], function() {
  console.log('Something is done');
});
```

If you are looking for a far more robust solution, you can also use [later.js](https://bunkat.github.io/later/), that claims to work on browser and offer a full featured cron interface, at the cost of bundle size.

Comment: @Imagine17 Take care, there was a typo in my code (missing parenthesis on the first getHours).

Answer (score 0):

I would at first calculate the distance to the next 12 am/pm and after the first run you can add 12 hours in every call or create an interval.

To get the distance to the first run you can use difference of `Date.now` and the moment to run:

```
var n = new Date()
if(n.getHours()>=12){
  n.setHours(24);
}else{
  n.setHours(12);  
}
```

After this set all smaller units than hour to zero.

After initial call:
`setInterval(this.fetch_datetime, 12 * 60 * 60 * 1e3)`

There is also a vue plugin which provides help for intervals and callbacks https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-interval

You should also have in mind that setTimeout and setInterval are not absolutely correct. They may get triggered a few millisecounds to early or to late. So calculating the difference to the next execution moment can trigger the function double.